# Simply typed lambda calculus vs Hindley-Milner type system

Tags: functional-programming, type-inference, lambda-calculus, parametric-polymorphism, hindley-milner

I have recently been learning about λ-calculus. I understood the difference between  untyped and typed λ-calculus. But, I'm not much clear about the distinction between the **Hindley-Milner type system** and the **typed λ-calculus**. Is it about [**parametric polymorphism**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism) or are there any other differences ?

Can anyone clearly point out the differences (and similarities) between the two ?

Comment: Of interest: [Types and Programming Languages (The MIT Press)](https://www.amazon.com/Types-Programming-Languages-MIT-Press/dp/0262162091) This book covers type systems by building on untyped lambda calculus. See [λ-Calculus extensions: meaning of extension symbols](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9548/268) for list of typing systems covered in book.

Comment: Of interest: [An Introduction to Functional Programming Through Lambda Calculus (Dover Books on Mathematics)](https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Functional-Programming-Calculus-Mathematics/dp/0486478831) Another book that teaches lambda calculus and    moves onto typing. This is a very basic book but if you are new to typing and lambda calculus this is the first book to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I look at the relationship between **typed λ-calculus** and **Hindley-Milner type system** is that **typed λ-calculus** is **λ-calculus** with types added. You can do **typed λ-calculus** without needing **Hindley-Milner type system**, e.g. all of the types are declared, they are not inferred.

Now if you were to write a [strongly statically typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_typing) programming language based on **typed λ-calculus** and wanted to omit [type annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature) allowing the types to be [inferred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference) then [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) is used and most likely you would use **Hindley-Milner type system** or a variation of it.

Another way to think about this is when creating a programming language based on **typed λ-calculus** is that the compiler would have [phases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler#Three-stage_compiler_structure), one of which would use **Hindley-Milner type system**. The order of the phases would be:

1. Syntax check  - [Lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)
2. Semantic check - [Parser](http://Parsing)
3. [Type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) - [Hindley-Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system)
4. [Type checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system)
5. ...

Another way to think about this is that a [type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system) has a set of [type rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_rule) and that [Hindley-Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) is a specific type system with a specific set of type rules. One of the main benefits of [Hindley-Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) is that it is time efficient for inferring types and also has many of the typing rules [sought](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9548/%CE%BB-calculus-extensions-meaning-of-extension-symbols) in [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), e.g. [Let-polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Let-polymorphism_2) and  [parametric polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#Monomorphism_vs._polymorphism). In the real world if you are creating a programming language and want the types to be inferred then you want that to be done in a reasonable amount of time, e.g. seconds. Since [inferencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inference) can lead to [combinatorial explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion) an efficient set of rules is often sought and that is one of the main reasons why [Hindley-Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system) is so often used or referenced.

For real world programming languages based on **typed λ-calculus** see [System F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F).

Answer (score 1):

The distinction is that there are many [type systems for the lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typed_lambda_calculus#Kinds_of_typed_lambda_calculi), and Hindley-Milner is one of them. Hindley-Milner is a type system with parametric polymorphism. This is what we call generics in today's programming languages.